Problem when using docker to load data postgresql db server when launching
There is an error:

python: can't open file '/apps/load_data.py': [Errno 2] No such file
or directory

The file origin is right in local.
Plus the database is not populated
Yet, in the Dockerfile, I COPY to ./load_data.py the script and COPY to ./src/scripts/data/load_data.py
The app folder was never used as a path in the Dockerfile, and I even tried doing a RUN mkdir apps and COPY to apps/load_data.py
In the following the scripts (loading from the postgresql container with command line and bash works though)
Dockefile:
# Utilise une image officielle de Python comme image de base
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Définit le répertoire de travail dans le conteneur
WORKDIR /usr/src

# Create the data folder (shouldn't have to do that)
RUN mkdir data
RUN mkdir apps

# Installe les dépendances nécessaires pour psycopg2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

# Copie les scripts dans le conteneur
COPY ../src/scripts ./scripts

# Copie les fichiers de données dans le conteneur
COPY ../data ./data

# Copier load_data.py
COPY ./src/scripts/load_data.py ./apps/load_data.py

# Copier load_data.py
COPY ./src/scripts/load_data.py ./load_data.py

# Copie le script wait_for_docker.sh dans le répertoire de travail
COPY wait_for_docker.sh ./
RUN chmod +x wait_for_docker.sh

# Installe les dépendances Python via pip (si requirements.txt est présent)
# COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
# RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Définit la commande par défaut pour exécuter le script Python après PostgreSQL est disponible
CMD ["./wait_for_docker.sh", "postgres", "python", "./scripts/data/load_data.py"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.11'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: tsunamis_
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../src/scripts/data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql  # Mount init.sql to initialize DB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:  # Healthcheck to ensure PostgreSQL is ready
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U admin"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5

  python-script:
    build:
      context: ..  # The context should be at the root of the directory containing 
docker-compose.yml
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: python_script_container
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy  # Wait until PostgreSQL is healthy
    volumes:
      - ../src/scripts:/usr/src/scripts  # Mount the scripts directory
      - ../data:/usr/data  # Mount the CSV files directory
    environment:
      DB_NAME: tsunamis_
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
    command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 50 && python load_data.py"]  # Execute the load_data.py script after startup

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy  # Wait until PostgreSQL is healthy
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin_data:


"can't open file '/apps/load_data.py'"  that path doesn't look right. Which command or line of code is actually causing that error?

@Phil it is the docker logs of the python_script_container and I can't figure out where they find the apps folder (when I create it, or when I don't in the Dockerfile). In any case the load_data.py exists and the if created it is in the apps folder. I can't even have the container existing if the script is not found. Which is really strange also.

There's a big difference between /apps which is in the filesystem root and ./apps which would be /usr/src/apps in your image. Are you sure you don't have /apps somewhere in your code?

This is why it is so strange, that is all the code I have to launch the containers (+ init.sql and load_data.py where apps is not mentioned ever)

Maybe I can try and change the Workdir in the dockerfile, but if I look into the postgres container, there is no apps directory so why should there be in the python_script one ...
